# Greenify ruins my Samsung Keyboard Input Languages

Tags: keyboard, languages, input-methods, disable-app, greenify

I've installed this Greenify app on my non-rooted Galaxy S3. It really does the magic after hibernating some of the non-system apps (e.g. FB, Twitter, etc.)  - phone runs faster, battery drains down much slower.

But, oh hey, it removes my multiple input languages from the Samsung Keyboard. I can no longer swipe the space bar for another language - it's either English or another language I am heavily using.

Switching the Greenify off of the Accessibility Mode brings the multiple languages option back to the space bar, but practically disables the Greenify itself.

Any chance I could fix that - still run the Greenify and keep my system keyboard options?

Comment: Thanks, but you are not reading - disabling Greenify in accessibility does help (I described that above), but my problem is that I still want to continue using Greenify.